# Is it considered appropriate to upvote my friend if I find their posts useful?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

Say a specific user is my friend. Naturally, I follow the user's activity and each time he/she posts an answer, I upvote it. Of course I do that only after a careful read and if I find it useful, at least for the OP.

Is it considered inappropriate? Would some automatic algorithm track my upvoting activity and cancel it?

And what if that friend also gives me the same attention?

Again, I don't mean [upvoting just because we're friends](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/serial-voting/info). The relation just attracts attention to the user's activity which is followed by probable upvote (as that friend is by all means no less than the ultimate professional).

Comment: An expert in one question will be a complete noob with other questions. Perhaps your friend only answers questions where they know what they're talking about (I try to do that), but it's not safe to assume this is always the case. Up voting a person is useless, each answer has to be considered individually.

Comment: If its in the normal course of events then theres no issue, if you follow all their questions I'd suggest up voting only the truely exceptional ones to avoid being a sock puppet with a human attached

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Is it considered inappropriate?

No, it is not appropriate, not if this is the *only* person you upvote. Voting should be on the merit of the post, not the person.

> I do that only after a careful read and finding it useful

That's a different matter then. But do you upvote *other* people's posts as well? You should be.

> Would some automatic algorithm track my upvoting activity and cancel it?

Yes, there is and yes, it would - if this is done excessively. We have voting ring detection algorithms in place. In short - don't overdo it.

Comment: fair enough :).